# Upload a large blob from Appengine blobstore to Google Drive using Python using Drive SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

The Python Drive API requires a "local file" to perform a resumable file upload to Google Drive, how can this be accomplished using Google Appengine which only has blobs and no access to a local file system.

Under the old doclist API (now depreciated) you could upload files from Google Appengine blobstore to Google Drive using the code below:

```
    CHUNK_SIZE = 524288 
    uploader = gdata.client.ResumableUploader(
    client, blob_info.open(), blob_info.content_type, blob_info.size,  chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE, desired_class=gdata.docs.data.DocsEntry)
```

The key part is using blob_info.open() rather than providing a reference to a local file.

How can we accomplish the same using the new Drive API?

Note the files are fairly big so a resumable upload is required, also I know this can be accomplished in Java but I am looking for a Python solution.

Many thanks,
Ian.

Comment: I know nothing of the Python sdk, but remember you can always use the http REST API itself.

Comment: Have look at: http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately PyDrive has exactly the same problem as the official Google Drive SDK - it too requires a local file instance but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the older GData client library and the Documents List API. If you use the new Drive SDK and the Google APIs Python client library, you can use the [MediaIoBaseUpload](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/apiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload-class.html) class to create a media upload object from memory instead of from a file.

Comment: Hi Eric - I am already using the Drive API, I will check out MediaIoBaseUpload and hopefully that will do the trick. The Doclist code was just to show how I used to accomplish this in the now depreciated doclist API. Cheers Ian